# Trying to wrap <span> around first word of multiple word strings only works on two word strings and not more than two

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to wrap a  around the first word of multiple word widget titles. I have used the answer from here:

[Revised Wordpress function to put a Span around the first word of the Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263792/revised-wordpress-function-to-put-a-span-around-the-first-word-of-the-title)

and adjusted it to look like:

```
function add_label_to_post_title( $title = '' ) {
    $ARR_title = explode(" ", $title);

    if(sizeof($ARR_title) > 1 ) {
        $first_word = "<span>".$ARR_title['0']."</span> ";
        unset($ARR_title['0']);
        return $first_word. implode(" ", $ARR_title);
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}

add_filter( 'widget_title', 'add_label_to_post_title' );
```

and it works great on two word titles. However 3 or more word titles are not affected.

I tried modifying the code with:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\>)\b\w*\b|^\w*\b/', '<span>$0</span>', $string);
```

from here:

[wrap <b>-tag around first word of string with preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833435/wrap-b-tag-around-first-word-of-string-with-preg-replace)

and had the same result, works great on two word titles but three or more are not affected. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Please find code snippet using array below

```
function add_label_to_post_title( $title = '' ) 
{

    $ARR_title = explode(" ", $title);

    if(sizeof($ARR_title) > 1 )
    {
        $ARR_title[0] = "<span>".$ARR_title[0]."</span>";
        return implode(" ", $ARR_title);
    }
    else
    {
        return $title;
    }

}
echo add_label_to_post_title ("hi there this is test code");
```

Comment: preg_replace function you mentioned works well in my environment? Is there any specific words which are not working for you? Can you give me an example of words with which you have tested above code?

Comment: Here are two examples of strings that it is not working on:

'Can You Help?'
'Recent Business Thumbs'

I do notice that:

'About|Focus Bromley'

is working correctly.

Thank you

Comment: Here are two more examples that are not working: 'A selection of special offers featured in our vMall' Bulletins featured in our vMall' @Amit

Comment: Sorry, correction. All of those strings work with the test "echo" function that you have provided. But when I put that code into the `widget_title` filter it only works on 2 word strings. Is there something about the `add_filter( 'widget_title', 'add_label_to_post_title' );` Wordpress filter tat is causing this?

Comment: I am not much aware with WordPress. You can check source code of Word Press

Comment: I am going to repost this on "Wordpress Answers". Another bit of info I found the need to use this on `the_title()` and it works fine. So it must be something with the `widget_title` hook.